# Console Calculation

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio

I'm having trouble and I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code.

The code should execute the following

1. When executed within the terminal the **MoveAmount** and **Move** should end up equal to each other.
2. Side A  should follow the equation
   **(x*a)/(a+b)** and execute with the correct value. (***x representing the move and A and B representing their perspective ratio***).
3. Move - SideA = Side B
4. Move = SideA + SideB

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working and I am unable to get the code to  create the proper output.

If I try to input my values based on this graph [image] the Calculated Movement of Side A and B return incorrectly and the output does not follow the desired perameters above.

If anyone can give me any tips let me know.

```
using System;

namespace Example
{
    class CalculatedMove
    {
        public double Move = 0.0;
        public double SideARatio = 0.0;
        public double SideBRatio = 0.0;


        public CalculatedMove(double SideARatio, double SideBRatio, double Move)
        {
            this.Move = Move;
            this.SideARatio = SideARatio;
            this.SideBRatio = SideBRatio;
            
        }

        public virtual void SideA()
        {
            double SideA = 0.0;
            SideA = (Move * SideARatio) /(SideARatio + SideBRatio);
            Console.WriteLine("Calculated Side A Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideA);
        }

        public void SideB()
        {
            double SideB = 0.0;
            SideB = Move - SideARatio;
            Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Side B Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideB);
        }

        public void MovementAmount()
        {
            double MovementAmount = 0.0;
            MovementAmount = SideARatio + SideBRatio;
            Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Move Amount is {0:00.0000}", MovementAmount);
        }

    }
   

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double Move, SideARatio, SideBRatio = 0.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Move Amount ");
            Move = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Side A Ratio");
            SideARatio = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Side B Ratio");
            SideBRatio = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            CalculatedMove objMove = new CalculatedMove(Move, SideARatio,SideBRatio);
            objMove.SideA();
            objMove.SideB();
            objMove.MovementAmount();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing that jumps out to me is the parameter order when calling … `new CalculatedMove(Move, SideARatio,SideBRatio);` … ? ... the constructor uses a different order of the parameters… `public CalculatedMove(double SideARatio, double SideBRatio, double Move)` … this doesn’t look right… I am pretty sure you want to call the constructor like… `new CalculatedMove(SideARatio,SideBRatio,Move);`

Comment: What you need to query is the accuracy of floating-point number calculations. You can also try to use `decimal` to achieve your purpose.

Comment: Start debugging and if you still can't find the problem, come back with some debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as JohnG said, **the sequence of parameters is wrong** when calling parameters.

Then when calculating SideB, SideARatio should not be subtracted, but SideA should be subtracted.

Finally, `Move` should be `SideA+SideB`, not `SideARatio+SideBRatio`.

```
using System;

namespace Example {
    class CalculatedMove {
        private double move =0.0;
        public double Move {
            get { return move; }
            set { move=value; }
        }
        private double sideARatio=0.0;
        public double SideARatio {
            get { return sideARatio; }
            set { sideARatio=value; }
        }

        private double sideBRatio = 0.0;
        public double SideBRatio {
            get { return sideBRatio; }
            set { sideBRatio=value; }
        }

        private double sideA = 0.0;
        public double SideA {
            get { return sideA; }
            set { sideA=value; }
        }
        private double sideB = 0.0;
        public double SideB {
            get { return sideB; }
            set { sideB=value; }
        }
        private double movementAmount = 0.0;
        public double MovementAmount {
            get { return movementAmount; }
            set { MovementAmount=value; }
        }

        public CalculatedMove(double SideARatio, double SideBRatio, double Move) {
        this.move=Move;
        this.sideARatio=SideARatio;
        this.sideBRatio=SideBRatio;
        }

        public virtual void SideAMove() {
        SideA=(Move*SideARatio)/(SideARatio+SideBRatio);
        Console.WriteLine("Calculated Side A Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideA);
        }

        public void SideBMove() {
        SideB=(Move*SideBRatio)/(SideARatio+SideBRatio);
        Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Side B Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideB);
        }

        public void MovementAmountMove() {
        MovementAmount=SideA+SideB;
        Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Move Amount is {0:00.0000}", MovementAmount);
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
        double Move, SideARatio, SideBRatio = 0.0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Move Amount ");
        Move=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Side A Ratio");
        SideARatio=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Side B Ratio");
        SideBRatio=Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        CalculatedMove objMove = new CalculatedMove( SideARatio, SideBRatio,Move);
        objMove.SideAMove();
        objMove.SideBMove();
        objMove.MovementAmountMove();
        Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As 3.Move - SideA = Side B :

```
  public void SideB()
  {
        double SideB = 0.0;
        SideB = Move - SideARatio; // Here is the problem;
        Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Side B Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideB);
  }
```

Fix public void SideB()

```
  public void SideB()
  {
        double SideB = 0.0;
        SideB = (Move * SideBRatio) /(SideARatio + SideBRatio);
        Console.WriteLine("The Calculated Side B Movement is {00:00.0000}", SideB);
  }
```